# Passing Data using MMDrawerController to the center controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, mmdrawercontroller

I am using MMDrawerController to make an application in swift. within the application I have to pass data from the side drawers to the center drawers. I found this for how to pass info in Objective-C.

```
MainViewController *mainViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainViewController"];
mainViewController.projectName = @"TWSFG.vis";
mainViewController.indexScript = 150;

[self.mm_drawerController setCenterViewController:mainViewController withCloseAnimation:YES completion:nil];
```

But when I try to do this I have no reference to self.mm_drawerController. Any help for how to do this would be very appreciated.

Comment: are you using a tableView in SideBar?

Comment: Yes, I am using a tableView in the SideBar

Comment: I think that is the Question to your Answer.... if you Want to move to center View Controller.. you have to implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath method